# Adding all sub-pages to the menu manager

Tags: customization, admin, menus

Is there some simple way which would allow one to add a page to a menu (through the menu manager interface) and be able to define if the inclusion of this item should automatically add all subpages up to a specific depth?

Essentially, the logic I am trying to use here applies to a user adding a new page with content then associating this page as a sub-page of another and by doing so this page automatically shows up on the fronted whenever a specific custom menu is requested where such logic was added.

Not sure if the logic of the menu manager allows for such dynamic list capabilities to take place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a plugin for that:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-descendants-as-submenu-items/